# HTTP ERROR 500 - php

Tags: php

I'm trying to open the index.php page but the browser shows this error:
currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I do not think that the error is on the config.php page because the database configuration works fine with pages other than the index.php

here is my index.php code:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'config.php'; 

    login_required(); 
    $users = count_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users"); 
    $emails = count_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM subscribers"); 
    $subs = count_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM subscriptions"); 
    $nls = count_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM newsletters"); 
    $mess = count_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM messages"); 
    $temps = count_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM templates"); 
    $title = "Home!"; 
    $content = <<<EOF 
    <h3>current stats</h3> 
    <p>$users user registered</p> 
    <p>$emails subscribers</p> 
    <p>$subs newsletter subscriptions</p> 
    <p>$nls newsletters</p> 
    <p>$mess messages</p> 
    <p>$temps templates</p> 
    EOF; 
    include 'layout.php'; ?>
```

the layout page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
        <head> 
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 

            <title><?php echo $title; ?> » my newsletter app</title> 
            <!-- Stylesheets --> 
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> --> 
        </head> 
        <body<?php if ($mini == true) { ?> class="mini"<?php } ?>> 
            <div id="header"> 
                <h1><a href="index.php">my newsletter app</a></h1> 
            </div> 
            <?php if ($nonav == false) { ?> 
            <div id="nav"> 
                <a href="messages.php"<?php if($tab == 'mess') {?>class="current"<?php } ?>>messages</a> 
                <a href="subscribers.php"<?php if($tab == 'sub') {?>class="current"<?php } ?>>subscribers</a> 
                <a href="newsletters.php"<?php if($tab == 'nl') {?>class="current"<?php } ?>>newsletters</a> 
                <a href="templates.php"<?php if($tab == 'temp') {?>class="current"<?php } ?>>templates</a> 
                <span class="right"> 
                    <a href="logout.php">log out</a> 
                </span> 
            </div> 
            <?php } ?> 
            <div id="container"> 
                <h3><?php echo $title;?></h3> 
                <?php echo $content; ?> 
            </div> 
        </body> 
    </html>
```

the config page:

```
<?php  
    // DB Settings 
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost'); 
    define('DB_USER', 'abdulsme_admin'); 
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'bypass'); 
    define('DB_NAME', 'abdulsme_newsletter'); 

    define('FROM_EMAIL', 'no_reply@ohyeahemail.com'); 
    define('FROM_NAME', 'oh yeah email!'); 


    session_start(); 
    require_once 'classes.php'; 
    $mini = false; 
    $nonav = false; 
    error_reporting(0);
    ?>
```

Comment: What if you delete all code and write just hello ?

Comment: it works when I just write hello

Comment: See server's log, and let us know so we can help you :)

Comment: Great!! you check step by step to identify the exact place of error. 1. by adding configphp 2.adding rest of index page code 3. And by adding layout.php

Comment: how can I see the server log?

Comment: just edited my question

Comment: The location of server log is depend on different web server, you should provide that in your question and tag first.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove all indenting from your closing EOF; line.**

From the PHP manual:

**It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.**

**If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line.**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
$content = <<<EOF 
<h3>current stats</h3> 
<p>$users user registered</p> 
<p>$emails subscribers</p> 
<p>$subs newsletter subscriptions</p> 
<p>$nls newsletters</p> 
<p>$mess messages</p> 
<p>$temps templates</p> 
EOF;
```

**To:**

```
$content = "
<h3>current stats</h3> 
<p>$users user registered</p> 
<p>$emails subscribers</p> 
<p>$subs newsletter subscriptions</p> 
<p>$nls newsletters</p> 
<p>$mess messages</p> 
<p>$temps templates</p> 
";
```

**Or to:**

```
$content = <<<EOF
    <h3>current stats</h3> 
    <p>$users user registered</p> 
    <p>$emails subscribers</p> 
    <p>$subs newsletter subscriptions</p> 
    <p>$nls newsletters</p> 
    <p>$mess messages</p> 
    <p>$temps templates</p> 
EOF;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should this change help to resolve a server error?